# Authentication with passeport in node and angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication

I'm trying to build an angular 2 application,here is my backend implementation

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.json(401, error);
    if (!user) return res.json(404, {message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});

    var token = auth.signToken(user._id, user.role);
    res.json({token: token});
  })(req, res, next)
});
```

now i want to implement my frontend side with angular 2 but i have no idea how to code services and components.
i tried this

```
Login(user) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/local', user)
              .map(res => res.json())

        });
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this https://github.com/domfarolino/angular2-login-seed

as well as https://github.com/domfarolino/angular2-login-seed/tree/master/src/app/login

Should be fairly easy to implement on you side